# Are there moral theories in which necessity and duress do not excuse or justify an immoral action?

Tags: ethics

People tend to claim that an immoral action is excused or justified at gun point or other types of duress in which "free will" is severely limited. And the law is on their side. What are the arguments against that?

Comment: What would the point of such a legal system be? If the law couldn't guide action beforehand, but we still "dislike" the action taken, then what, are we so hung up on our gluttony for punishing others that we satisfy our displeasure for such a crass reason?

Comment: The first mistake is to bring up the law in a moral discussion. Morality & the law can be different from each other. Morality implies that an act is universally applied everywhere & to all people. For instance, abortion oppoents claim abortion is murder. They don't just mean abortion is murder in their state. They mean every where abortions are performed! These people know abortion is leagal but still persist abortion is murder. The reason is because there is a moral claim being made. The law doesn't need to be brought up at all. Abortion is o e example. You likely can invent others.

Comment: i don't see what relevance free will is, but a good question nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

The Principle of Alternative Possibilities (PAP) says that someone is only morally responsible for their actions if it were possible for them to do differently. [According the the SEP's article on the topic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/alternative-possibilities/), almost everyone has taken this principle for granted until very recently. One objection to PAP is interesting because it is easy to see how it could form the basis for a moral theory.

Lets say Alice was brainwashed to rob a bank. Upon being arresting and the brainwashing undone, Alice says that she would have robbed the bank **even if she had the ability to act differently**. She acted as a [compelled but willing agent](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/alternative-possibilities/#CompButWillActi). A moral theory based on what someone would have done if they could have acted differently would find Alice responsible for the robbery. I believe [Hume](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hume-freewill/) proposed a theory much like this, but honestly I am not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 1):

All moral frameworks keep the person accountable for their decision, regardless of whether according to the given framework the person should resist or comply.

Answer (score 1):

They don't excuse or justify the action they excuse or justify the actor. That's a crucial difference. As far as I know some jurisdiction have edge cases where you are charged with a crime and subsequently pardoned, so that in effect you get out scot free, but the action itself is still viewed with contempt. Idk catch22 cases or trolley problems where you could only act wrong for example.

The thing is in that "ought implies can" so if the action that you'd define as ethical is impossible and no ethical option is possible then you can but it's rather pointless to blame that on the individual, because there's by definition nothing they could have done about that.

A slightly different case is actio libera in causa, where the action itself happens under circumstances which made an ethical action impossible, but where it was deliberate acting that maneuvered you inside that situation. Like if you drink up the courage to commit a crime and then aren't culpable because not in control of your senses. In that case the drinking itself could be penalized as you didn't control the action itself but already intended and manufactured the outcome in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> One test of responsibility that might be proposed would limit the responsibility of someone acting under coercion if she acts in a way that minimizes the total amount of harm (invoking the “lesser-evil principle”). So, for instance, we might deny that a person is responsible for choosing to injure another to avoid being killed, but hold her responsible if she chooses to kill someone to avoid being injured herself. Though this principle is intuitively plausible, we clearly do not accept it in other, non-coercive contexts. For instance, we do not permit one to snatch a spare kidney from one individual to save the life of another. Although we might add conditions to this test to make the limitation of one’s responsibility harder to obtain, and therefore more in line with our intuitions, it remains unclear that there is any widely-accepted moral principle of this sort that would cover all cases equally well.

It might depend on what the coercion is

> Instead of a moral test, one might propose a psychological test, on
> which acquiescing to a coercer’s demands in a way that harms others is
> justified if the net value of doing so is sufficiently great to the
> coercee. Roughly speaking, this is Feinberg’s approach, taken up by
> Murray and Dudrick as well. (See Feinberg 1986; and Murray and Dudrick
> 1995.)

and arguably how psychologically threatening it is to whoever is being coerced, though

> if the justification lies in the pressure on the will, then it would
> seem one might have the same justification for yielding to temptation
> that one has for acquiescing to a mortal threat.

Clearly, if you cannot do otherwise you are excused, and at times are even justified

> When a coercer has the power to enforce his decision regardless of
> what the coercee chooses to do, this may provide the coercee a
> justification for failing to engage in an exercise in futility

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/coercion/#EffeCoerCoerResp

In conclusion, I quote

### "There is no single, widely agreed upon theory that explains when an agent is or is not responsible for something that happens in the world"

Comment: i have no idea why my answer wasn't upvoted. any ideas? does it not answer the question enough or do you disagree with the answer, what? it is well referenced